How to generate normally distributed Sobol sequences arrays in Python?
I would like to use Sobol sequences to produce normally distributed sequences. In particular, I would like to generate the "equivalent" of the following random numbers:
Z = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, [5, 10, 4])

I was thinking to use Scipy.Stats.Qmc where there is MultiVariateNormalQMC function, but I am a bit confused on how to structure the inputs in order to get an array with shape = (5,10,4) as I need. I was not able to find any example online. Any idea?

try this approch import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import qmc
Define the target mean and covariance matrix
mean = np.zeros(4)  # Mean vector of zeros for 4 dimensions
cov = np.eye(4)     # Identity matrix as covariance for standard normal distribution
sampler = qmc.MultivariateNormalQMC(mean=mean, cov=cov, seed=42)
In this case, we need 5 * 10 = 50 samples for a shape of (5, 10, 4)
samples = sampler.random(5 * 10)
sobol_normal_samples = samples.reshape(5, 10, 4)
print(sobol_normal_samples)

Define the mean and covariance for a standard normal distribution.
Use qmc.MultivariateNormalQMC from scipy.stats with the mean and covariance to create a Sobol-based sampler.
Generate samples using sampler.random(50) to get 50 samples (for reshaping later).
Reshape the generated samples to (5, 10, 4) for the final output.

Thank you @FatimaMir. May I ask you why seed=42?

@FatimaMir I tried this approach, and it does not show the mean 0 and standard deviation 1 that I would like to have, as correctly done by the random number generator

I'm assuming you are interested in the univariate normal distribution, not a multivariate normal distribution. Please make that explicit in your question because you refer to np.random.normal but also MultiVariateNormalQMC.
You can use MultiVariateNormalQMC, but for a univariate application, you might just prefer to manually do inverse transform sampling: pass the output of the uniform Sobol' sequence generator through the inverse CDF of the normal distribution (stats.norm.ppf).
However, you have to be careful for two reasons:

Sobol' sequences need to have length equal to a power of two to preserve their properties. See Warning at scipy.stats.Sobol.
You need to think about what you want to be a low discrepancy sequence and what you want to be independent. For instance, is this a batch of 50 (5 x 10) independently scrambled Sobol' sequences of length 4?

Assuming the answer to the last question is yes, then some code is:
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

batch_shape = (5, 10)
sequence_length = 4

sequences = []
# SciPy does not currently provide a good API for producing
# batches of independently scrambled low-discrepancy sequences. 
# To get independent sequences, we have to provide a different
# RNG seed to each.
for i in range(math.prod(batch_shape)):
    # better would be to start with a `default_rng` and
    # use `SeedSequence` to get a new RNG.
    qrng = stats.qmc.Sobol(1, seed=i)
    uniform_sequence = qrng.random(sequence_length)
    normal_sequence = stats.norm.ppf(uniform_sequence)
    sequences.append(normal_sequence.ravel())

sequences = np.stack(sequences)
sequences = sequences.reshape(batch_shape + (sequence_length,))

Update your question with more information about which axes are supposed to contain the normally-distributed transformation of a low-discrepancy sequence, and I'll update this answer accordingly.
